# RStudio is blank when opened

Tags: r, rstudio

I have just installed the latest versions of R (3.1.0) and Rstudio (v0.98.507) on a Windows 7 machine, 64 bit.

The R GUI works OK, but when I open the RStudio.exe only a blank window opens.  I've tried re-installing R and RStudio.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you figure it out? I am in the same boat

Answer (score 4):

By choosing the R version I wanted to use I was able to use Rstudio again.

To choose the R version you want to use with Rstudio do the following;

1. Click the CTRL key (don't let go)
2. Click on the Rstudio icon
3. Choose the version you want in the pop-up window.

Comment: this worked perfectly well for me. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It works, I installed two different version of R, so I think Rstudio doesn't know which one to use.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu users where @neal's solution doesn't work.

$ rstudio --no-sandbox

related to: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1944468

Answer (score 2):

Download the 64bit version and reinstall it. 
The same for Linux

Answer (score 2):

**FOR LINUX:** this happens to me on cloud instances. A solution is forcing software rendering of RStudio. You need to start RStudio, get to the black screen, close Rstudio black screen, do my solution below in the terminal with Rstudio closed, then start Rstudio again.

In terminal:

```
sudo nano ~/.config/RStudio/desktop.ini
```

APPEND THE FOLLWING TO [General] section (leave whatever is there and add the line below):

```
[General]
desktop.renderingEngine=software
```

Again this is for Linux, but there may be a similar issue in Windows and you may be able to force software rendering.

Comment: First time using Linux OS, tried but doesn't help

Comment: You need to start RStudio, get to the black screen, close Rstudio black screen, do my solution above, then start Rstudio again. Should solve it

Answer (score 0):

Press down Ctrl key and then click on RStudio icon to launch. A dialog box asks you about the R version. Choose the one that actually exists (you might see an R version which does not exist; confusing RStudio)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows10 64bit.

After following the hold Ctrl and clicking RStudio icon.

Change the Rendering Engine: to Software.

This fixed the problem on my machine.